# Using Visual Studio 2013 For Java

Tags: java, debugging, compilation, visual-studio-2013

Is there any way to manage/debug/compile Java projects in Visual Studio 2013?

I saw a thread on here from 2012 for version 2010, but I figured they may have changed it a lot since then.

Comment: AFAIK, VS yet don't have support for JAVA language.

Comment: Do you have a good reason for wanting to do this?  I'm not sure its worth it, even if it were possible.

Comment: Hey, why the downvotes? It's a good question with potential for garnering interesting info we might not be aware of.

Answer (score 7):

Debugger Support

Current features of the debugger include:

```
Support for multiple JVMs
    Support for the 32- and 64-bit releases of the standard JDK 6 and 7 (HotSpot VM)
    Support for the 32- and 64-bit releases of JRockit R28.x 
Full support for “Java Runtime Environment” exceptions in the Debug → Exceptions dialog
    Standard packages and exceptions are shown in the Java Runtime Environment category
    Users can add their own exceptions by name
    Users may select which exceptions the debugger should break on at the time they are thrown
    Unhandled exceptions automatically trigger a breakpoint
    When an exception is thrown, a message is printed to the output window (similar to the way it’s handled in C# debugging)
```

see [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bc561769-36ff-4a40-9504-e266e8706f93) article for more information